# Joystick with the Arduino

Tags: arduino

How do i go about using the joystick with an Arduino?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is brilliant!

a new [Joystick from Sparkfun](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/9760) with the example code to getting it running on the [Arduino](http://www.sparkfun.com/Code/Joystick_Shield_Example.zip)

Comment: That shield is awesome! I'll have to keep it mind for some future projects I have in mind (hint: MAME cabinet :D)

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you are using a non-USB joystick.

See http://www.built-to-spec.com/blog/2009/09/10/using-a-pc-joystick-with-the-arduino/

Answer (score 1):

Non-analog joysticks aren't that hard to make by yourself. There is an [instructable](http://www.instructables.com/id/Mini-Joystick-with-Fire-Button/) that explains how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in using a Wii nunchuk as a joystick controller for your Arduino, you might want to check out these sources:

http://todbot.com/blog/2008/02/18/wiichuck-wii-nunchuck-adapter-available/

and

http://www.windmeadow.com/node/42

Answer (score 1):

take a look here  http://www.liquidware.com/projects/26/TouchShield+Tetris

it's a project about TouchShield Tetris